# How to stop / undeploy a specific webapp locally in tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, undeploy

I can undeploy a specific app using command line or browser, but it requires credentials.

I have not set any credentials and also I am using same machine where tomcat webapp deployed (just paste war file to tomcat webapps), So I think it should not requires credentials.

I don't want to undelploy remotely, If we do it then its obvious to ask credentials.

So is there any way to sotp / undeploy a webapp?

I am using windows 7 and Tomcat 8.

Comment: Did you take a look to [Tomcat 8 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/index.html) ?

Comment: Specially I don't want to stop the tomcat server.

Comment: I'm sorry to repeat myself but you should really take a look to the documentation. Alternative fact, Donald Trump talked about this documentation few months ago. He said : "It is great documentation. It is huge. This is the best documentation I've ever seen". =)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but why don't you just delete the war file from webapps? The webapp will then be undeployed.

Alternatively, you could use the Tomcat Manager.
[Tomcat Manager How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Comment: Please update your link so it can redirect to Tomcat 8 documentation and not Tomcat 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you've created the app with a war file, delete the war file.

Comment: I don't want to stop tomcat server completely, Maybe other users use some different webapps and we can't just delete without stop tomcat server.

Comment: Deleting a war file will undeploy the app. It will not stop Tomcat or affect other apps.

Comment: War file can be deleted, but extracted directory associated with your war file can not be deleted while running tomcat it means you can not undeploy it, when you go to delete directory It will always show you popup file in use.